# Div not showing in FBJS

Tags: javascript, fbml, fbjs

I have code that I have in a Static FBML tab on my fan page.  This div starts out as hidden but when I hit the Blah link it doesn't change to visible.  Any ideas why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function showstep1() {
    document.getObjectById('step1').setStyle('visibility','visible');
}
-->
</script>
<div id="step1" style="visibility:hidden">
Test
</div>
<a onclick="showstep1();">Blah</a>
```

http://pastebin.com/aPVJr7YA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
document.getObjectById('step1').setStyle('visibility','visible');
```

To

```
document.getElementById('step1').style.visibility = "visible";
```

Comment: I cannot view that page.  Something else must be going on, though, because your example code works with my modification.

Comment: Try using `display:none;` and `display:block;` instead of visibility.

Comment: Tried that and nothing.  This is the error IE is giving me: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDR; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Timestamp: Wed, 10 Nov 2010 23:13:22 UTC


Message: 'undefined' is null or not an object
Line: 165580005
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Shot-Dogs/118232434893207?v=app_4949752878

Not very helpful.

Comment: Figured it out.  instead of having all the javascript I can just do initially the style="display:none" in the div then do <a clicktoshow='divname'


Thanks for your help Stephen